# Trying to make an efficient query while searching for a specific value and a range of dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
 select * from sales_order a
join sales_order_item b
 on order_id = entity_id
 where b.agent_id = 09
 AND a.creation_date >= '2022-01-01' 
AND a.creation_date <= '2022-12-01';
```

> sales_order is a table that contains the header information of an
> order
>
> sales_order_item is a table that contains the line information of each order

Take a look at this example

Sales_order has these columns (order_id, creation_date)

| order_id | creation_date |
| --- | --- |
| 34....... | 2022-02-01 |
| 45....... | 2022-04-12 |
| 56....... | 2022-07-22 |
| 67....... | 2022-08-05 |

---

Sales_order_item has these columns (entity_id, item,agent_id)

| entity_id | item | agent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34....... | 3242344213 | 09 |
| 34....... | 3442344213 | 09 |
| 34....... | 2342344213 | 09 |
| 45....... | 3142344213 | 09 |

Both tables join by order_id and entity_id.

What would it be the best way to obtain all the order_ids from a specific agent_id and a given range of dates?

---

**Desired result:**

I want to obtain all the order_ids (not duplicates) that belong to the agent_id = 09 and between 2022-02-01 and 2022-05-20

| order_id |
| --- |
| 34 |
| 45 |

What would it be the most performant way to solve this?

Comment: What is the output of the `query` you tried up there?

Comment: What's about `select distinct order_id from ...` rest as your statement?

Comment: Which search is more "selective"? In other words, please specify the estimated percentage of rows selected when searching in the first table (by creation_date), compared to searching on the second table (by agent_id).

Comment: Very unlikely distinct is a good idea when aiming to get the best performance.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed hey pal, my query returns duplicates

Comment: @TheImpaler i may have 100 rows per each order in table sales_order_item. Each order is unique in sales_order but in table sales_order_item it may have many rows related, you get me?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Hey, yeah.. i guess so

Comment: try @h.m.i.13 suggestion

Comment: @h.m.i.13 "distinct" is not really performant at all

Comment: @new_programmer Yes, I understand that table organization. However, from the point of view of the optimizer what it matters is the selectivity. Please provide hard numbers on it, so we can help you.

Comment: @TheImpaler if i search only using creation_date in table 1 and the given range (2022-02-01 and 2022-05-20) i got +34.000 rows